# How to use ^ in negating a character class in Python

Tags: python, regex, parentheses

I am trying to write a code that prints the only the number of cookies in "We just received $10.00 for 40 cookies."
Here are the some codes I tried. None worked and I don't  know why.

```
    import re
    x = 'We just received $10.00 for 40 cookies.'
    y = re.findall('[^$][0-9.]+',x)
    print (y)

    import re
    x = 'We just received $10.00 for 40 cookies.'
    y = re.findall('*^\$[0-9]+',x)
    print (y)   

    import re
    x = 'We just received $10.00 for 40 cookies.'
    y = re.findall('^$[0-9]+',x)
    print (y)
```

Comment: In two of those cases the caret isn't even _in_ a character class. What exactly were you expecting here?

Comment: The use of `^` as a negation for a class set is covered in the [Python Regular Expression HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html): "You can match the characters not listed within the class by complementing the set. This is indicated by including a `'^'` *as the first character of the class* [emphasis added]. For example, `[^5]` will match any character except `'5'`. If the caret appears elsewhere in a character class, it does not have special meaning. For example: `[5^]` will match either a `'5'` or a `'^'`."

Comment: <space><number(s)><space>: `re.findall(r"\s(\d+)\s", x)`

Comment: Your first regular expression, `[^$][0-9.]+`, matches anything that isn't a "`$`", followed by one or more instances of a digit or a period (i.e., "`.`"). The catch is that "1" is not a "`$`", and it is followed by one or more instances of a digit or a period, so your regular expression matches "10.00".

Comment: It will even match the final `s.`, `s` being a non-dollar-sign and `.` being included in `[0-9.]`

Comment: While the second one is not a well formed regex, and the third one makes little sense since `^` requests a beginning-of-line position and `$` request an end-of-line one

Answer (score 2):

This looks long, but I'm going to explain what's going on in your different attempts, to help you understand why they didn't work.

Your first attempt specifies that a match consists of:

- any character that is not the end of the line  — `[^$]`
- consists of one or more characters `0–9` or `.`— `[0–9.]``

```py
re.findall('[^$][0-9.]+',x)
```

so it matches `['10.00', ' 40', 's.']`.

Your second attempt, as written, throws an error because `*` is a regex wildcard that means 'any number of the preceding character/group'. You haven't put anything before it, nor have you escaped it, so the computer doesn't understand it.

```py
re.findall('*^\$[0-9]+',x)
```

Your third attempt looks for:

- the start of a line — `^`
- immediately followed by the end of aline — `$`
- followed by one or more digits — `[0-9]`

this doesn't match anything in your string, and is unlikely to match anything as it doesn't include a line break.

```py
re.findall('^$[0-9]+',x)
```

This returns an empty list: `[]`.

If you want to find the number of cookies, not the price, or anything else, you need a regex that will detect a number—consisting of an unknown number of digits—that doesn't include characters like `.`, and is not preceded by `$`.

You can specify whitespace with `\s`, and you can 'capture' part of a regex match using `( )`. This is useful if you need to specify something before and after the text you want to keep—like the whitespace—but don't want to keep it.

So, the regex:

```py
re.findall(r'\s([0-9]+)\s', x)
```

finds:

- a whitespace character — `\s`
- followed by one or more digits, which are captured — `([0-9]+)`
- followed by a whitespace character — `\s`

This returns: `['40']`.